# Can the `ConcurrentHashMap::get` method return a "dirty" valuekkkjjjjj?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

While writing the value via `put` method if another thread tries to read the value for the same key, what will the reader thread get? The old value, the new value or some "junk" value?

Answer (score 1):

The second thread's `get` will see the new value, if the first thread's `put` operation has completed.  Otherwise, it will see the old value.

Note that "completed" is not a clearly defined notion in this context.  The operation could be deemed to be completed *before* the `put` call returns.

But you **can** rely on two things:

- The second thread won't see a garbage reference.  It will always be a reference to a valid object.
- The second thread will<sup>1</sup> be able to see all writes made to the object made by the first thread prior before it called `put`.

The latter is guaranteed by the Java memory model as a consequence of the *happens-before* that the javadoc talks about.

---

<sup>1 - This assumes there are no other updates to the object in the intervening interval between the first thread's `put` and the second thread accessing the object returned by the `get`.</sup>

Comment: *The operation could be deemed to be completed before the put call returns.* Do you mean that the second thread's call to `get` can retrieve the value even before the `put` call returns - meaning that the value has been written to the map but the method call hasn't returned yet

Comment: Basically, yes.  There will be tiny window between `put` finishing the work and it returning.  (I was being a bit pedantic ...)

Comment: But that tiny window is *only* after the lock on the key is released right?

Comment: Yes.  (But the lock is on a segment, not a key.  Look at the source code.)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently *completed* update operations holding upon their onset. (More formally, an update operation for a given key bears a happens-before relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.)

Comment: Hi Andy Turner, Can you please elaborate with some example ?